# Itemize a text with many lines without writing 'item' explicitly at the beginning of every line

Tags: lists, itemize

Ok, this may be an easy one but I've been googling a lot without success.

I have a long text with many lines separated by the new line character. What I want to do is itemize this text so that every line corresponds to an item in a list. I definitely can do:

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item
\begin{itemize}
```

but the lines are just too many to start adding an `\item` code at the beginning of every line. I can definitely write a script to automate this process, but I want to know: Is there a way make a list in latex with items separated by the new line character instead of writing `\item` at the beginning of every item?

Let me know if I can be more clear.

Comment: If you have blank lines in between you can use (more or less) `\everypar{\textbullet}` but if you really mean every line you need (in addition) `\obeylines` as normally an end of line is treated as a space. (But I'd just use your editor to add the `\item`)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. You description is clear, but still would be nice to have something to start with. Furthermore, the test case would go a long way in clarifying any issues. Such as, are the lines all short text (a few words), or do they sometimes contain loner text that may spill over onto multiple lines in the output? Basically, produce a test case.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like the `easylist` package.  (Although it, too, reasonably expects something to mark an 'item'....)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on David Carlisle's suggestion you can issue `\obeylines` and set `\everypar` in a way that produces a bullet and appropriate spacing.  Enclosing everything in a `\bgroup...\egroup` will also limit the scope of these changes.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Some text to indicate the left margin.

\bgroup\obeylines\everypar{\hspace*{2em}\textbullet\enspace}
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
A text line that is to be an item.
\egroup

\end{document}
```